# PowerShell Get-ScheduledTask from specific file path

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a list of scheduled tasks from within the task scheduler. Seemingly when you run the Get-ScheduledTask cmdlet it would appear to be hard coded to look within the C:\Windows\Tasks. However, I need to export a list of tasks from C:\Windows\System32\Tasks. I have tried specifying this task path and changed the file type to. job as it said this is the file type for Task Scheduler Task Object that also did not work. Below is the error I seem to get when looking for the specific file path:

No matching MSFT_ScheduledTask objects found by CIM query for instances of the
Root/Microsoft/Windows/TaskScheduler/MSFT_ScheduledTask class on the  CIM server: SELECT * FROM MSFT_ScheduledTask  WHERE ((TaskName LIKE
'%')) AND ((TaskPath LIKE 'C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\ADPhoneBookScript')). Verify query parameters and retry.
At line:1 char:1

- Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName * -TaskPath "C:\Windows\System32\Tasks

I have tried many other fixes like moving to another folder in case of a permissions error but seemingly no joy.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. Run the command in an elevated prompt. Both of these worked for me to return a list of tasks once I elevated.

`Get-ScheduledTask`
and
`Get-ScheduledTask -Taskpath "\Our Tasks\*"`